# Simplest way to write bytes to a writer?

Tags: java, servlets, stream, writer

I have written an implementation of `HttpServletResponse` and I am overriding a method `getOutputStream` which needs to return a `ServletOutputStream`. The data that is written to said stream must be encoded using `UTF-8` and then written to a separate `Writer` that was passed in the constructor.

Here is my pseudo-code.

```
class StreamResponse implements HttpServletResponse {
    private final PrintWriter pw;
    StreamResponse(PrintWriter pw) {
        this.pw = pw;
    }
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return pw;
    }
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        // what do I do?
    }
    // other methods overridden
}
```

How can I most simply return an `OutputStream` that outputs to `Writer` `pw`? I would rather not include extra `.jar` files for this, but am open to including an additional `.java` file if that is the way to do it.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.apache.commons.io.output.WriterOutputStream`

It has multiple constructors e.g.

```
public WriterOutputStream(Writer writer, String charsetName)
```

or wider one

```
public WriterOutputStream(Writer writer, Charset charset, int bufferSize, boolean writeImmediately)
```

Just wrap your writer and `return new WriterOutputStream(pw, theCharSet)`

UPDATE: If you don't want to include the jar you can look at the code (it's rather simple) to get the main idea and write own OutputStreamWriter implementation